# "dispatch" keyword in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

What is the role of "dispatch" keyword used in `make-account` function shown on this page: https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/14wi/racket/objects.html

```scm
(define (make-account)
   (let ((my-balance 0))

      ;; return the current balance
      (define (balance)
         my-balance)

      ;; make a withdrawal
     (define (withdraw amount)
        (if (>= my-balance amount)
           (begin (set! my-balance (- my-balance amount))
                   my-balance)
           "Insufficient funds"))

     ;; make a deposit
     (define (deposit amount)
        (set! my-balance (+ my-balance amount))
        my-balance)

     ;; the dispatching function -- decide what to do with the request
     (define (dispatch m)
        (cond ((eq? m 'balance) balance)
              ((eq? m 'withdraw) withdraw)
              ((eq? m 'deposit) deposit)
              (else (error "Unknown request -- MAKE-ACCOUNT"  m))))

      dispatch))
```

The Racket documentation mainly mentions about web dispatch (https://docs.racket-lang.org/search/index.html?q=dispatch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dispatch` is just the name of one of the procedures made under the lexical scope together with `my-balance` and the helper procedures.

It is also the returned value from the `make-account` procedure and functions as message passing procedure to the roll your own class. Calling it will return a procedure that can be used to access/mutate the object data, hence the name.

Dispatch is not unique to message passing in object systems so you will find the wording similar when it comes to handling requests in a web server application and other stuff that handles something on request/triggers.

Comment: dispatch is not a value so why without parentheses? Also, it should only work as (dispatch some_m). So how is simple 'dispatch' working?

Comment: @rnso It *is* a value; functions are "first-class" values in Scheme. `make-account` is a function that returns a function (and `dispatch` is the function it returns).

Comment: All symbols in code are variables so when you do `(+ a b)` Scheme evaluates `+`, then the rest of the operands in any order before it applies the result of the evaluation of the operator with the result of the evaluation of the operands. `+` is a variable that evaluated to a procedure. `dispatch` is a variable that evaluates to a procedure/closure. With higher order procedures you pass procedures and they can be lambdas or they can be bounded to variables. `(map add1 '(1 2 3)) ; ==> (2 3 4)`. since `dispatch` is the tail call it returns the procedure object so it's the result of `make-account`

Comment: So I could use any other name or term in place of 'dispatch'? I tried and it worked. Only that 'dispatch' sounded like a keyword (in contrast to names like myfunction etc).

Comment: @mso You can put anything that exists. eg. it needs to be bounded if it's a variable. Remember `(define (procname arg ...) ...)` is the same as `(define procname (lambda (arg ...) ...)` and the variable is the same as any other. You could simplify it by not giving it a name at all and just place the lambda as last argument and the result would be the same.

Comment: @mso notice what `dispach` does. It returns `balance`, `withdraw` and `deposit` so you do `((account 'deposit) 10)`. The first expression is evaluated. It becomes `deposit` procedure from the object and it gets applied with 10 as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

In `(define (dispatch m)`, `dispatch` is not a keyword, or special form. It is the name of the defined function.